# updating from sfdx-cli to sf

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, sf

I've set up actions that run on deployments in git. These scripts use the sfdx commands to deploy and various other functions.  Now I want to move them from `sfdx` and to the new `sf` cli.  Is there a painless transition to sf from sfdx that doesn't require me to change all the commands from sfdx to sf syntax in my scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be taken care by `sf(v2)` as mentioned in the official documentation  [Move from sfdx (v7) to sf (v2)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_move_to_sf_v2.htm). Once you migrate successfully, both `sf` and `sfdx` commands will work as `sfdx` is now aliased to `sf`.

Screenshot from the above link:

[image]

Screenshot from my windows machine where I have migrated to sf (v2) recently.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Saroj.  I did notice this is the documentation, but wasn't sure that this would work as expected.

Comment: Yes it will work, I have added a screenshot from my machine for your reference. Also I have seen VSCode Plugin still uses the sfdx versions of the commands, and it works without any changes.

Comment: Yes, I see the same after emptying my ~/.sf folder.  Looks good.  Thanks Saroj for the help!

Comment: Thanks Saroj, I also see this 

`sf version
@salesforce/cli/2.19.8 darwin-arm64 node-v17.1.0

sfdx version
@salesforce/cli/2.19.8 darwin-arm64 node-v17.1.0`

Comment: Could you please mark this answer as accepted then so future readers know this is the solution?

Comment: most certainly, my good sir